# Linux struct msghdr :: msg_iovlen type

Tags: linux, sockets

No practical reason, just wondering.
Why in Linux in msghdr struct, they use size_t type for msg_iovlen field? I found it a bit confusing, as size_t usually means "how much bytes".
Btw, in FreeBSD they use u_int for that field, and int is in Posix standard.

Comment: It arrived as part of the general 64bit support. In this case it prevents padding bytes turning up in the structure when you go from 32bit to 64bit

Answer (score 0):

See [`size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t):

> size_t is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator as well as the sizeof... operator and the alignof operator... size_t can store the maximum size of a theoretically possible object of any type (including array). On many platforms (an exception are systems with segmented addressing)